# SQL native query with ResultSetMapping object return null

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to query SQL Server with `pdo_sqlsrv` through a Symfony 3/Doctrine 2 application.

I have an SQL query and I would like to bind the result with my entity by using a `ResultSetMapping` object:

**This is the function of my SupplierRepository.php**

```
class SupplierRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function getSuppliers()
{
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
    $rsm->addEntityResult('AppBundle\Entity\Supplier', 's');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'T_TIERS', 'code');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'T_LIBELLE', 'name');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'T_ADRESSE1', 'address1');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'T_ADRESSE2', 'address2');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'T_ADRESSE3', 'address3');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'T_CODEPOSTAL', 'zipcode');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'T_VILLE', 'city');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'T_SIRET', 'siret');

    $sql = 'SELECT  s.T_TIERS,
            s.T_LIBELLE, 
            s.T_ADRESSE1, 
            s.T_ADRESSE2, 
            s.T_ADRESSE3, 
            s.T_CODEPOSTAL, 
            s.T_VILLE, 
            s.T_SIRET 
            FROM RFFOURNISSEURS s
            WHERE (s.T_NATUREAUXI=?)
            AND
            (s.T_FERME=?)';

    $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    $query->setParameters(array(1 => 'FOU', 2 => '-'));
    
    return $query->getArrayResult();
}
}
```

**This my entity Supplier.php**

```
/**
 * Supplier
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="supplier")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\SupplierRepository")
 */
class Supplier
{

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", unique=true)
 */
private $code;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address1", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $address1;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address2", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $address2;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address3", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $address3;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="zipcode", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $zipcode;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $city;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="siret", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $siret;

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getCode(): int
{
    return $this->code;
}

/**
 * @param int $code
 */
public function setCode(int $code)
{
    $this->code = $code;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName(): string
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @param string $name
 */
public function setName(string $name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getAddress1(): string
{
    return $this->address1;
}

/**
 * @param string $address1
 */
public function setAddress1(string $address1)
{
    $this->address1 = $address1;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getAddress2(): string
{
    return $this->address2;
}

/**
 * @param string $address2
 */
public function setAddress2(string $address2)
{
    $this->address2 = $address2;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getAddress3(): string
{
    return $this->address3;
}

/**
 * @param string $address3
 */
public function setAddress3(string $address3)
{
    $this->address3 = $address3;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getZipcode(): int
{
    return $this->zipcode;
}

/**
 * @param int $zipcode
 */
public function setZipcode(int $zipcode)
{
    $this->zipcode = $zipcode;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getCity(): string
{
    return $this->city;
}

/**
 * @param string $city
 */
public function setCity(string $city)
{
    $this->city = $city;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getSiret(): int
{
    return $this->siret;
}

/**
 * @param int $siret
 */
public function setSiret(int $siret)
{
    $this->siret = $siret;
}
```

**Error/result**

The query is well executed, I have an array of 1025 elements which is correct, but they are NULL, and not Supplier objects:

```
array(1025) {
    [0]=> NULL
    [1]=> NULL
    [2]=> NULL
    [3]=> NULL
    [4]=> NULL
    ...
}
```

Any ideas? Is it a type error? During debugging I was able to see that the data is getting pulled from the database:

[image]

Comment: Can i ask is there a really need of native query ? It can be done using doctrine

Comment: Hi M Khalid Junaid, thanks for answer, i chose option of native query because my query here is more simple that the real one i have wich contain a join to a table, and i'm not very conftable with query builder yet, but i will dothis way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields of your `Supplier` entity are all private. Changing them to public should allow the RSM to set them. You should also pull something from the database to fill the `id` field.

```
class Supplier
{
    public $id;
    public $code;
    public $name;
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks miken32 !! It was resolved by filling field "id" of my entity (i also changed field from private to public, but it didn't solve).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was searching my DB for an entity which was having a composite key as a PK i.e. in the entity exist two properties which have the annotation `@Id`.

Why do I mention this? Because it can be that composite keys bring some more restriction in context of Doctrine and `createNativeQuery`. When I am querying the DB with `ResultSetMapping` and I am using the method `addFieldResult`, I also receive an array with the length equals with the number of rows in select but with null in all properties.

My solution was to use

```
$rsm->addScalarResult( 'T_TIERS', 'code');
```

I was taking the information from this [doctrine2/issues/6273](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6273)